# converting SU file to ASCII format in seismic unix using OpenSeaSeis

Tags: geophysics, seismology

I have tried to convert a Seismic SU file to ASCII format in seismic unix using openseaseis module named "sutoascii".

**I have already tested the SU file by opening it in SeaView Seismic Viewer and then tried to convert it to "ASCII" format using the following command:**

```
sutoascii <inputSUFilename >outputASCIIFilename bare=0 index=1
```

*The ASCII file is created as an output file but it gives an error while converting that **"number of samples in header differs from number for first trace"***

Now to check whether the Resulting ASCIIFile is valid and working, I have tried to open it in SeaView Seismic Viewer again to cross-check but it shows an error and is unable to open the file.

*Can anybody tell me how to correct this?*

Comment: If this is a command line, shouldn't "bare=0" and "index=1" come before the first redirect symbol?

Comment: @BarryCarter yes, this is a command line and its not necessary for it to come before the first redirect symbol.
For reference regarding syntax, please refer to http://www.seismicunix.com/w/Suascii

Comment: That page says nothing about where options go, but ">" and "<" are interpreted by the shell, not by sutoascii. The program doesn't even see "bare=0" and "index=1" above.

Comment: @abhinavgoyal02 - It would be nice to know how this ended... did the answer here help? What did you actually end up doing?

Answer (score 5):

The number of samples in the input binary header from the SEGY file does not match the NSAMP trace header.  I would first confirm:

1. What # of samples is in the binary SEG-Y header.
2. The number of samples you expect in each trace
3. Dump the su trace header for     number of samples. You can use
   SUGETHW and the keyword for # of samples is "ns".

If the error is in an individual trace header, you can overwrite that with SUSETHW.